# How do I update a query correctly

Tags: php, mysql

Whats wrong with my code?
Basically what I'm trying to do is add a number and update a field in the sql with what is connected to the variable. But since steamids look like this `STEAM_0:0:123123123` or `STEAM_0:1:123123123` I get this

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':0:14166834' at line 1

This is just for learning, so I know my code has useless echos, but its just to see it being added and making sure i was doing it correctly anyways

addmoney.php

```
<?php
include("inc/config.php");
$mysteamid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mysteamid']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE steamid='$mysteamid'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$cash=mysql_result($result, 0, 'cash'); // outputs 7th
echo $cash;
$newcash= $cash + "10000";
echo "\n";
echo $newcash;
mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET `cash` = $newcash WHERE `steamid` = $mysteamid") or        die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

index.php contains a working formdata its not really required with the error in my code.
my main problem is this line from addmoney.php which is

```
$mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET `cash` = $newcash WHERE `steamid` = $mysteamid") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What is the type of the 'steamid' column?

Comment: What's the schema for your table? Is cash an int or a varchar? Your quoting is very inconsistant. Either always use `` round a table or column name or never do. Either treat a number as text (with ' or " in php, with ' in sql) or treat it as a number, without.

Comment: also, consider using prepared statements rather than including variables in the SQL.

Comment: Thank you guys this question is resolved :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `steamid` field in your DB is a string *(it seems to be, as possible values are `STEAM_0:0:123123123` and `STEAM_0:1:123123123`)*, you must use quotes arround the value :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET `cash` = $newcash WHERE `steamid` = '$mysteamid'");
```

Using `mysql_real_escape_string()` is necessary, as it escapes quotes **inside** the variable you pass it as a parameter -- but you still have to put quotes **arround** the string, in your SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query you surrounded your $mysteamid value with simple quotes, and in the second query you didn't. If the steamid is a string type, you need to surround the value with quotes, like

```
"UPDATE $tbl_name SET `cash` = $newcash WHERE `steamid` =' $mysteamid'"
```